# Do multiple commands in one call to DAML's Command Submission Service result in one or many transactions?

Tags: daml

The `commands` field on the [Commands](https://docs.daml.com/app-dev/ledger-api-introduction/proto-docs.html#commands) object takes a list of `Command` objects. The description reads

> Individual elements of this atomic command.

Does that mean the list of commands will result in a single transaction? Are the commands guaranteed to be committed in the order supplied, in the sense that the corresponding sub-transactions in the transaction tree occur in that order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They result in a single transaction, as indicated by https://github.com/digital-asset/daml/blob/52d2026b2a57c9d82e7d53d6d694dcf775de4209/ledger-api/grpc-definitions/com/digitalasset/ledger/api/v1/command_submission_service.proto#L39 and https://docs.daml.com/app-dev/ledger-api-introduction/proto-docs.html#submitrequest .